# replace static AutoMapper API; replace a Map method inside a Profile

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm replacing static AutoMapper API:

So, before I had a `Profile` like:

```
public class DigitalResourceProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<DTO, Domain>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Domain, DTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Attachs, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<AttachDomain>, List<AttachDTO>>(src.Attachs)))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Timestamp, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime()));

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<AttachDTO, AttachDomain>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<AttachDomain, AttachDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Timestamp, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime()));
    }
}
```

From now on, this profile class is like:

```
public class DigitalResourceProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<DTO, Domain>();

        this.CreateMap<Domain, DTO>()
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.ForMember(dst => dst.Attachs, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<AttachDomain>, List<AttachDTO>>(src.Attachs)))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Timestamp, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime()));

        this.CreateMap<AttachDTO, AttachDomain>();

        this.CreateMap<AttachDomain, AttachDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Timestamp, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime()));
    }
}
```

However, I dont know how to replace `.ForMember(dst => dst.Attachs, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<AttachDomain>, List<AttachDTO>>(src.Attachs)))`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a way to call the Map() method from a Profile without using the static API ?

Comment: Regrettably, not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the static API, you can pass the mapping engine through the Profile contructor.

You will find below a unit test which is using Unity.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public class TestA
    {
        public TestC valueA { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestB
    {
        public TestD valueB { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestC
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestD
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly IUnityContainer appContainer = new UnityContainer();

    public sealed class MappingConfiguration : Profile
    {
        private readonly IMappingEngine mappingEngine;

        // Inject mapping engine through constructor
        public MappingConfiguration(IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
            : base()
        {
            this.mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<TestA, TestB>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.valueB, o => o.ResolveUsing(src => 
                    this.mappingEngine.Mapper.Map<TestD>(src.valueA)));
            CreateMap<TestC, TestD>();
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MappingTest()
    {
        // AutoMapper configuration
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => appContainer.Resolve(type));
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        appContainer.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);
        appContainer.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>(new InjectionConstructor(config, mapper));

        appContainer.Resolve<IConfiguration>().AddProfile(new MappingConfiguration(appContainer.Resolve<IMappingEngine>()));

        // Check config
        mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var testIn = new TestA { valueA = new TestC { value = "This is a test" } };
        var result = mapper.Map<TestB>(testIn);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me.  But why are you adding the Configuration and MappingEngine to the IOC Container? I followed a similar approach but created instances of both classes and then added IMapper to my IOC container instead.